# Find Control in repeater dynamically with Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have hard time to find textbox values in my repeater control. On button click i need to get textbox value corresponding to textbox which are inside of button which is clicked.

So i have :

Textbox1  ---> which have to be bound with Button1
TextBox2 ----> which is bound with Button2

```
<span>Question :</span><span>my second content <br /></span><span>Answer : </span><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ctl00$TextArea" type="text" id="MainContent_ctl00_TextArea_0" value="6454" />
```

Add Question

---

Question :abcdedf 
Answer : Add Question

Right now i have jquery function which get which is clicked:

```
 $(".addAnswerButton").click(function () {

        //var quantityBox = $("#TextArea", $(this).parent());
        var tr = $(this).closest("text")
        alert(tr.val());
        //quantityBox.text = "Hello there";
        //var currentValue = quantityBox.val();
        $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').first().val("clicked");

        //quantityBox.val(parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
    });
```

Ive got it working partially with:

```
$(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').first().val("clicked");
```

Where i get set textbox text, but then again, if i click second button, nothing happends.

What an i doing wrong? How can i get value from specific textbox?

**UPDATE**

now i go with solution where i add custom attribute to each control:

```
    <span>Question :</span>
<span>my second content <br /></span>
<span>Answer : </span>
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ctl00$TextArea" type="text" id="MainContent_ctl00_TextArea_0" value="654" mydataid="2" />

    <button id="MainContent_ctl00_answerQuestion_0" Class="addAnswerButton" onclick="Click()" mydataid="2" >Add Question</button><hr /><span>Question :</span><span>abcdedf <br /></span>

    <span>Answer : </span><input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ctl01$TextArea" type="text" mydataid="1" id="MainContent_ctl00_TextArea_1" value="654" />

    <button id="MainContent_ctl00_answerQuestion_1" Class="addAnswerButton" onclick="Click()" mydataid="1">Add Question</button>​
```

So right now i can get custom atribute from onclick event by doing this:

```
$(".addAnswerButton").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).attr("mydataid");
    alert(pos);
 //   $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').first().val("clicked");
});
```

But how do  i get textbox control which have samme custom attribute name as button?

**Update 2**

After 70 tryes i finally figured it out (my first tryes with Jquery)

**solution**

```
$(".addAnswerButton").click(function() {
    var pos = $(this).attr("mydataid");
    results = $('input[type = "text"][mydataid="'+pos+'"]').first();
    alert(results.val());
});
```

So point is, you are getting custom attributes "name", and then searching for a textbox with same attribute name.

Comment: Can you show your html structure?  are they all siblings or only siblings of the relative element?

Comment: Can you create a js fiddle with the html and the jquery you have? It'll help loads when trying to debug it.

Comment: fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/TcSWV/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark them from server with some attribute and use it in your jQuery code.

The output from server would be like this:

```
<input type='text' data-item-id='1'>First</input>
<inpyt type='button' data-item-id='1'></input>

 <input type='text' data-item-id='2'>Second</input>
    <inpyt type='button' data-item-id='2'></input>
```

After that once button is pressed, get it's data-item-id and search for textbox with the same attribute value.

Comment: I load repeater dynamicly from code behinde, can u show how to add data-item-id ?

Answer (score 1):

Edited after the comments.

I head to your jsfiddle and make it work with this:

```
$('[id*="answerQuestion"]').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children('[id*="TextArea_' + $(this).attr('id').substring($(this).attr('id').length - 1) + '"]').val('clicked');
});
```

Explanation:

1. I realize that your ids where answerQuestion for the buttons and TextArea for the txt.
2. In the function i made a selector who works with the TextArea id (the substring adds the 
   index to it)

That's it! It's a little tricky but it's the best solution i found.

Hope this helps!

Greetings, sorry if there are some english inconsistencies :)!

Comment: i cant do it that way, because ids are dynamic